# Angular Datatables get all selected rows

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, angular-datatables

I am using Angular Datatables in one of the application and have used the select extension as specified in the documentation like the following:

```
<table class="table animate__animated animate__fadeIn" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" [id]="tableId">

</table>
```

and the options are defined as follows:

```
    this.dtOptions = {
        info: false,
        order: [],
        select: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'selectAll',
            'selectNone'
        ]
    };
}
```

Now the select functionality is working fine, but I need to get the selected rows when I click on a button. How can I do this ? Is there any option in the Datatables API for accessing selected rows ?

Documentation - https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/select

In the core datatables, there is an option for adding the `action` callback. But not sure whether it will work with `selectAll`

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation please?

Comment: Please find it here: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/select

Answer (score 1):

1. Get selected rows:

`myTable.rows({ selected: true })`

2. Get data of selected rows:

`myTable.rows({ selected: true }).data()`

3. [Get id's](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().ids()) os selected rows (For this is usefull use [rowId](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId) and ajax) :

`myTable.rows({ selected: true }).ids()`

And then with this information, stored in a variable, you can iterate, filter... etc.